# xslt code to remove unused imported schemas from an xsd

Tags: java, xslt

I have a huge xml schema which contains lots of unused xsd with their schema locations. These are not reffered any  where in the whole file. Is there a way to remove these unused imported xsds and do the cleanup using xslt.

Comment: Do you know that all imported schemas are not used and therefore the XSLT can just remove any `xs:import`? Or do you expect the XSLT to check which imported schemas are not used and remove them based on that check?

Comment: Some of the xsd imports are reffered in the schema, but many are not used anywhere.The idea is to remove only unused imports.

Answer (score 1):

Run them through an identity transform with specialized empty templates matching the `xs:import` elements that you want to remove. The exact criteria depends on how you can identify the unused (filename, within a directory, etc).

Here is an example of how to exclude a particular schema import, identifying it by the filename in the `@schemaLocation`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--example of how to remove an import like: 
         <xs:import schemaLocation="some/path/to/unwanted-schema.xsd"/> 
     -->
    <xsl:template match="xs:import[ends-with(@schemaLocation, 'unwanted-schema.xsd')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could expand the match criteria, or create several empty templates matching the unwanted `xs:import` elements. All other content will be copied forward and preserved.